# Access content selector in the class for a custom element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

Custom elements allow you to access the inner html of the custom tag when it is used, via the `<content></content>` selector along with some specification for which content is pulled into this view.

I'd like to be able to access this data in my class without wrapping the tag.

I tried the following: `<content ref="content"></content>` and `this.content` to reference it following the [databinding ref attribute](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5) strategy Rob Eisenberg favors, but `console.log(this.content)` yields `undefined` at every phase in the element lifecycle.

A workaround I thought of was to place the `<content>` tag in another element, pull out the text using jquery, cache it, and remove that element via `ref` attribute, but this seems inelegant.

How can I access this data in the es6 class associated with the custom element?

Example scenario:

**some-view.html**

```
<template>
    <customelement>Hello World</customelement>
<template>
```

**customelement.html**

```
<template>
    Something, but not a content tag
</template>
```

**customelement.js**

```
export class CustomElement {
    get foobar () {
        //Somehow ascertain "Hello World" without displaying it in customelement
    }
}
```

In this example, the custom element could be assumed to be included globally.

Comment: would the `@processContent` decorator work for you?  http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/9
not sure if I fully understand your scenario- consider adding an example showing the intended usage of your custom element.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Looking at the docs, I'm not sure how to proceed and how the process function would look given those parameters. I've updated my question with a minimal example, hopefully this clears it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We no longer use the `content` element. As of the RC, we use the `slot` element. That being said, the `slot` element doesn't support the `ref` binding, as the slot element kinda "disappears" and is replaced with the content being projected. This is because in the Shadow DOM spec, `slot`s aren't actually elements, they are 'processing instructions`.

Comment: Okay, no problem. How do I access the data without using either a content tag or slot? I'd prefer to grab the content without modifying the DOM of the output.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that shows what you can access in terms of content at the various component lifecycle stages.

https://gist.run?id=e372bdb91990d08ad49cdf39753cc622**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./my-element"></require>

  <my-element>
    <div repeat.for="i of 5">${i}</div>
  </my-element>
</template>
```

**my-element.html**

```html
<template>
  Hello!
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

**my-element.js**

```js
import {inject, processContent, noView} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class MyElement {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    alert('constructed:\n\n' + this.element.innerHTML);
  }

  created() {
    alert('created:\n\n' + this.element.innerHTML);
  }

  bind() {
    alert('bind:\n\n' + this.element.innerHTML);
  }

  attached() {
    alert('attached:\n\n' + this.element.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested, and realized I need to add one more point of clarification - the custom element should still process and render as normal, I just need to extract the content - as you do here - and proceed as it would have.

Comment: So, I think the repeat div is complicating things. Take a look at this gist: https://gist.run/?id=6b24e48255af21f8e93dd7ae12e65162 - I'd like to extract "Whatever" at some point without a `<slot>`